# Prove that $\int_1^{\frac{1+z}{1-z}} \frac{d^n}{dz^n} (z^2-1)^n= -\frac{2(z-1)^n}{(n+1)! }\frac{d^n}{dz^n} (\frac{z}{z-1})^{n+1} $

Tags: derivatives, orthogonal-polynomials

> Prove that 
>   $$\int_1^{\frac{1+z}{1-z}} \frac{d^n}{dz^n} (z^2-1)^n= -\frac{2(z-1)^n}{(n+1)! }\frac{d^n}{dz^n} (\frac{z}{z-1})^{n+1} $$

Here are some attempts.

$\frac{d^n}{dz^n} (z^2-1)^n=2^n n! L_n(z),$ where $L_n(z)$ is the Legendre polynomials. I tried to use following formula for Legendre polynomials 
$$\frac{x^2-1}{n} \frac{d}{dx}L_n(x)=xL_n(x)-L_{n-1}(x).$$
But I get tripped up on it.

Comment: Have you tried applying the General Leibniz Rule for product differentiation?  We have derivativea of the products $(z^2-1)^n=(z-1)^n\,(z+1)^n$ and $(z/(z-1))^{n+1}=z^{n+1}(z-1)^{-(n+1)}$

Comment: @Dr. MV Thank You! Your comment helped me to prove it:)

Comment: Liza, you're welcome!  My pleasure.   If you post your solution here and let me know, I will "up vote" it.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr. MV, I posted

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{d^n}{dz^n} (z^2-1)^n$ is  Rodrigues' formula of Legendre polynomials, we use the following formula from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials.

$L(z)=\sum_{i=0}^n {{n \choose i} {-n-1 \choose i}(\frac{1-x}{2})^{i}}.$

Using the property ${n \choose i}=(-1)^i{-n+i-1 \choose i}$ and leting $k:=n-i$ we have

$L_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n {{n \choose k} {2n-k \choose n}(\frac{x-1}{2})^{n-k}}. $

Thus we have

$\int_1^{\frac{1+z}{1-z}} \frac{d^n}{dz^n} (z^2-1)^n= \int_1^{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}L_n(z) dx=\int^{\frac {z+1}{1-z}}_{1} \sum_{k=0}^n {{n \choose k} {2n-k \choose n}(\frac{x-1}{2})^{n-k}} dx=
\\= \left.\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} {2n-k \choose n}\frac{(x-1)^{n-k+1}}{2^{n-k}(n-k+1)}\right|_1 ^{\frac {z+1}{1-z}}=
\\=\frac{1}{n+1}  \sum_{k=0}^n {n+1 \choose k} {2n-k \choose n}(1-\frac{z+1}{1-z})^{n-k}\frac{1}{2^{n-k+1}}-\frac{1}{n+1}  \sum_{k=0}^n {n+1 \choose k} {2n-k \choose n}(0)^{n-k+1}\frac{1}{2^{n-k}}=
\\=\frac{1}{n+1}  \sum_{k=0}^n {n+1 \choose k} {2n-k \choose n}\frac{(2z)^{n-k+1}}{2^{n-k}(1-z)^{n-k+1}}=
\\=2\frac{(z-1)^{n} (-1)^n}{n+1}  \sum_{k=0}^n {n+1 \choose k} {2n-k \choose n}z^{n+1-k}(1-z)^{-2n+k-1}.$

Appling the General Leibniz Rule for product differentiation for $\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)^{n+1}$ we have
$-\frac{2(z-1)^{n}}{(n+1)!} \frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)^{n+1}=
=-\frac{2(z-1)^{n}}{(n+1)!}  \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{d^k }{dz^k}z^{n+1}\frac{d^{n-k} }{dz^{n-k}}\frac{1}{(z-1)^{n+1}}=\\
-\frac{2(z-1)^{n}}{n+1}  \sum_{k=0}^n {n+1 \choose k} {2n-k \choose n}\frac{(n+1-k)!}{(n+1)!}\frac{d^k z^{n+1}}{dz^k}\frac{n!}{(2n+k)!}\frac{d^{n-k} (z-1)^{-(n+1)}}{dz^{n-k}}=
\\ 2\frac{(z-1)^{n} (-1)^n}{n+1}  \sum_{k=0}^n {n+1 \choose k} {2n-k \choose n}z^{n+1-k}(1-z)^{-2n+k-1}.$

There is another proof. But it uses a little-known identity.

Comment: Liza, this is difficult to follow and there are seemingly several errors along the way.  Starting from the first line's last term, what happened to all of the derivatives and what happened to the terms with $x+1$?  -Mark

Comment: @Dr. MV Mark, I edited. Were are errors? I didn't apply the General Leibniz Rule for $\frac{d^n}{dz^n} (z^2-1)^n$ in this proof.